# Difference in Volatility Calculation from RiskMetrics 1996 to RiskMetrics 2006 VaR

Tags: value-at-risk

In the original legacy RiskMetrics documentation from 1996, volatility is calculated using a simple exponentially weighted moving average with some decay factor to determine the weights. This would be used in the calculation of volatility for variance-covariance VaR for example. In RM2006, is volatility still calculated this way? If not, how does it differ and can the 1996 method be substituted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The RiskMetrics 2006 methodology](https://www.msci.com/resources/research/technical_documentation/RM2006.pdf):

> Therefore, the new RM2006 methodology can be summarized as based
>   on a ARCH-like process with *long memory + Student distribution + residuals scale correction
>   + lagged correlations* between returns. All the ingredients contribute to the performances,
>   albeit possibly at different risk horizons or according to different performance measures. At
>   the end, the new RM2006 is clearly a more complicated methodology than the simple exponential
>   moving average of RM1994. This is the price to pay for the increased accuracies and
>   the possibility to reach long risk horizons

also:
[A gentle introduction to the RM 2006 methodology](https://www.msci.com/resources/research/technical_documentation/RM2006_introduction.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

No.  Vol in the 2006 is computed using scaled 1 year daily returns.